# surprising behavior from vim maps to 0, $, and ^

Tags: vim

The 0, $, and ^ keys are far from home row for how often I use them, so I thought I'd remap them to H, L, and U (respectively), like so:

```
nnoremap H 0     " start of line
nnoremap L $     " end of line
nnoremap U ^     " first non-blank character
```

But instead of doing what I'd expect, H and U put the cursor at the 6th character of a line, and L moves the cursor to the 5th or 4th character of the line below. WHat's happening, and can it be fixed?

Comment: Just tested it, and everything is working on my setup. Linux Ubuntu 12.10, vim - 7.3.547. Please re-test. The only thing i didn't do was that I didn't copied the comment part of the nnoremap command from your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nnoremap thinks that you want to map `H` to `0     " start of line`. It is not treating the `"` as the start of a comment.

You should move the comments to a different line.

```
" start of line
nnoremap H 0
" end of line 
nnoremap L $
" first non-blank character 
nnoremap U ^
```

Comment: Thank you! End-of-line comments work for vimrc lines that are NOT mappings, but of course mappings would take the whole line as part of their instructions.